# How Can I Download and Use a Matrix from Matrix Market?

Tags: julia

I am trying to write code to store a matrix to a variable directly from [Matrix Market's website](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/). Below is a sample URL that I'd use:

https://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/bcsstruc1/bcsstk01.mtx.gz

The example URL will download a `bcsstk01.mtx.gz` file. I need to extract the `bcsstk01.mtx` file. Then I need to use `MatrixMarket.mmread()` so I can save to a variable.

I first tried saving the downloaded file (or URL location) to a variable `A = HTTP.get()`, but lack of online resources and lack of knowledge led to no results. Then I used `HTTP.download()` and got the `.mtx.gz` file, but I can't unzip it. And finally, `MatrixMarket.mmread()` cannot read `.gz` files. So I'm stuck with a downloaded file I can't do anything with unless I manually unzip it.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaSparse/MatrixMarket.jl/issues/42

Comment: With the help of ChatGPT, I was able to make [this package](https://github.com/CHLOzzz/MMGet) to do it for me. Everyone feel free to use it. It's still a baby and I still don't know package management so be warned it could be buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the info from link in the comments and some fiddling, I managed to get the following:

```
using TranscodingStreams, CodecZlib
using Downloads

stream = PipeBuffer()
openstream = TranscodingStream(GzipDecompressor(), stream)
Downloads.download("https://math.nist.gov/pub/MatrixMarket2/Harwell-Boeing/bcsstruc1/bcsstk01.mtx.gz", stream)
for line in eachline(openstream)
    println(line)
end
```

This prints:

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real symmetric
48 48 224
1 1  2.8322685185200e+06
5 1  1.0000000000000e+06
6 1  2.0833333333300e+06
7 1 -3.3333333333300e+03
...
```

which I suppose is the desired data.